# The guestbook is getting populated too quickly

Tags: feature-request, april-fools, time-machine

The guestbook works well enough, except it's getting populated too quickly, resulting in memory usage growing when I keep a page open for long enough.

Normally I would suggest adding pagination, but the guestbook implementation my dad always used on his site, Dreambook, up until its shutdown [lacked pagination](https://web.archive.org/web/20121013035629/http://books.dreambook.com/vic2829/victor.html) so I guess that's not an optimal approach.

Instead, would introducing a bit of suspension of disbelief by silently dequeuing older guestbook entries past a certain limit (say, 256) work better?

Comment: Quick! Someone fix this bug before it becomes obsolete and it can't be fixed anymore!